# c++ - pass map<int, vector> by reference

Tags: c++

I would like to pass a map by reference to a function so that the function can modify it.  It would also be acceptable to for the function to create and return this map since it does not return anything else, but the pass by reference seemed easier. I'm not sure why I am getting the following error as I followed the suggestions in this post [c++ pass a map by reference into function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763397/c-pass-a-map-by-reference-into-function)

Error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::map<int, std::vector<double> >&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::map<int, std::vector<double> >*’
```

My Pseudo Code

```
void func(std::map<int, vector<double> > &my_map)
{
     /* do stuff with my_map */
}

int main()
{
std::map<int, vector<double> > specific_map;
func(&specific_map);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you passing the address of your map? - i.e. call it as `func(specific_map);`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore this worked, I read the post I mentioned wrong.  If you would like to type it up I will accept it as an answer

Comment: @rootmath question is unlikely to help anyone else in the future. Better delete it.

Comment: As @JonathanPotter said, change `func(&specific_map);` to `func(specific_map);` and it will work.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I appreciate that, and I know this is a community site, but I'd like to keep this question as a reference for my future self.  If its better to delete it, however, i will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your top function with `*` not `&`. `*` means the variable is a pointer and `&` (in the context of when you're calling a function) means "give me the address of this variable. So, you want to store the address of your variable in a pointer, and therefore want your function to take a pointer (`*`) and you want to pass it an address (`&`):

This is called *passing by pointer*. The function we create accepts a pointer to a map (*), and when we call the function we're creating a pointer (&) to our map:

```
void func(std::map<int, vector<double> > *my_map) // accept a pointer *
{
     /* do stuff with my_map */
}

int main()
{
std::map<int, vector<double> > specific_map;
func(&specific_map); // pass a copy of where specific_map exists in memory &
}
```

inside your first function you cannot use dot notation though. You will have to use arrow notation. This means you must do `my_map->size()` instead of `my_map.size()`.

---

Alternatively you can just pass your map by reference. This is a "new" feature in c++ which is *arguably* more readable and (again *arguably*) easier to understand:

```
void func(std::map<int, vector<double> > &my_map)
{
     /* do stuff with my_map */
}

int main()
{
std::map<int, vector<double> > specific_map;
func(specific_map);
}
```

and you can use dot notation here as usual, `my_map.size()` but this is *still a reference* to your original map. Note that in this second scenario the caller doesn't have to provide a reference to the variable, but just the variable itself, and yet we're still passing by reference. With pass by reference, no copy of the initial variable's pointer is made, so changes you make to the variable WILL effect the local variable (you're saving overhead here).

Comment: That wouldn't pass the variable by reference. The `&` in the function signature doesn't mean "pass an address".

Comment: Using a pointer is arguably easier to read for functions that mutate variables, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: *"pass by reference"* as generally used in Computing Science refers to passing by any pointer-like handle, as contrasted with *pass by value* where a copy is made.  Of course, now C++ has in-built references a la `std::map<int, vector<double>>&` it's potentially confusing.  The function in the question does expect an actual C++ reference, and the linked question focuses on their use.  Still, a bit harsh to call this outright wrong given the `&specific_map` is generating a pointer.

Comment: @TonyD passing by pointer is a pass-by-value - a copy of that pointer is made and passed.

Comment: @Jason how so? Passing by non-const reference is more than enough to tell the reader "this function changes the passed-in variable".

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That argument doesn't hold up because behind the scenes a reference is passed as a pointer. An argument that would hold up is simply saying that a C++ reference was meant specifically, and not a pass-by-reference in general.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You have to take the address at the call site, so you know the function takes by reference.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: again you're talking about the C++ implementation and (deliberately ;-P) ignoring the semantics... the Computing Science term "pass by reference" involves passing the pointer/handle/whatever-it-is by value.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore He either had to take the & out of his call TO func, or he had to change it to * in his function definition. He had 2 options, both just as correct as the other...

Comment: @TonyD I get that, but it's idiomatic in C++ to pass by non-const reference rather than by pointer if you want to change the variable. Suggesting that the fix is to change the signature and pass the address (even though it works) goes against the correct C++ learning process. A user should know what pass-by-value and pass-by-reference means in a C++ context.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore C++ does provide native non-const references, but the code generated is identical.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: a preference for C++ references is expressed in Marshall's FAQ and endorsed by lots of experts, but there are plenty of people and code bases in which pointers are used for arguments that may be modified, so I'd stop short of calling it idiomatic of the language.  In my opinion, the arguments either way aren't compelling.  Regardless, it would be nice if this answer made it much clearer how the implementations relate to C++ and Computing Science terminology.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You are coping a massive beating! Good luck ...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I've edited my answer to include an example of both pass by value and pass by reference. Your point about new c++ developers learning both methods is valid.